# How to avoid install / deploy spring boot fat jar to maven repo

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

We are using the spring-boot-maven-plugin's **repackage** task for packaging fat-jar (sample pom.xml below), and tried the `<attach>false</attach>`, but seems the fat-jar will be install / deployed anyway.

Currently, we configured maven-{install,deploy}-plugin's `<skip>true</skip>` to work around this issue, but not sure how to use boot plugin's `<attach>` or other ways to fix this.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>repackage</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>repackage</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <attach>false</attach>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Thanks

Comment: The question is: Do you need to run `mvn clean deploy` or `mvn clean install`? I would check if `mvn clean verify` is sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure it correctly like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>repackage</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>repackage</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <attach>false</attach>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: sorry, actually i mistakenly edited the code above manually, the actual pom configure is correct in git, i will edit the question above, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when I moved the fragment `<configuration><attach>false</attach></configuration>` to be a child of the `<plugin>` tag. I put it after the `<version></version>` tag.